# C++ copying out all the vowels of a string in another string | How to copy a char type in a string?

Tags: c++, string, char, ascii

I'm trying to take all the vowels of a string and copying them in a different string, in the order they appear. The string should only be one word (no spaces) and lower case english alphabet letters.

Example: If I enter "informatics" I expect an output of "oai".

I get an std::out of range error in the cmd box itself when I run the compiler

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s, s2;
    int i, j;
    char c;
    cout << "Introduceti sirul de caractere: "; cin>>s;

    j=0;
    for(i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        switch(s.at(i))
    {
        case 97: {j++; c=97; s2.at(j)=c;}
        case 101: {j++; c=101; s2.at(j)=c;}
        case 105: {j++; c=105; s2.at(j)=c;}
        case 111: {j++; c-111; s2.at(j)=c;}
        case 117: {j++; c=117; s2.at(j)=c;}
    }

    cout<<s2;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming the problem is at copying the vowel itself in the second string, so how is it generally done anyway? I couldn't just have a s2.at(j)=a, for example, as it would say that the variable a wasn't declared (of course), but I also assumed I couldn't just say it's equal to the ASCII code of the vowel, or could I? I don't even know. So I tried changing a variable on the spot having that vowel and then putting it in the string, but I get an error.

Comment: I think you're missing `break`s in the `switch` statement

Comment: Please clarify: Given "the quick brown fox" what is the expected output?

Comment: You never allocated your `s2` string correctly, thus you can't copy / replace anything there. Also as @ForceBru mentioned there are missing `break;` statements.

Comment: What does `97` and the other magic numbers mean? I assume you really meant `'a'`.

Comment: Strongly recommend using the character `'a'` rather than the raw ASCII code. 1) It's a lot easier for a casual reader to infer the intent of `'a'` than `97`. 2) it's easier to spot mistakes like accidentally using the wrong code. 3) The target system may be one of the few that does not use ASCII.

Comment: @user4581301 (regarding your first comment)Edited for clarification. (regarding your second one)I explained in the post itself why I didn't use the character a???? I don't even know how to, I'm clearly asking right there.

And I don't miss breaks? Why should I put breaks if I want to copy all the vowels, instead of just one?

Comment: You would use `case 'a':`

Comment: I see. Apologies for misinterpreting that bit. To use `a` as a character and not an identifier, you need to tell the compiler that you want a character literal by embedding the character in single quotes:  `'a'`.

Comment: I get the error "case label ''a'' not within a switch statement"

Comment: @Lastrevio You have to use single-tick not double. 'a', not "a"

Comment: That's what I used @ZanLynx

Comment: Well, is the `case 'a':` inside a `switch` statement?

Comment: Example: `case 'a': {s2.push_back('a'); break;}`. The `push_back` is important as `s2` has no storage for element `j` yet. `j`  is no longer necessary and is removed. There is no need for `c` as `'a'` can be directly placed into the string without stopping over in `c`. The importance of the `break` has already been covered.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler, skip the switch (also, don't forget the capitals):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const auto vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"s;

    cout << "Introduceti sirul de caractere: \n"; 

    auto input = string();
    if( getline( cin, input ) )
    {
        cout << "Recieved: " << input << "\n";

        auto output = string();
        for( const auto c : input )
        {
            if( vowels.find(c) != string::npos )
            {
                output.push_back(c);
            }
        }

        cout << output;
    }
}
```

See it run live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d370b038d8b5dff)</kbd>.

Some would argue that, rather than a hand-rolled for-loop, one should use `std::copy_if()` from the standard library:

```
copy_if( begin(input), end(input), back_inserter(output), 
         [&]( auto c ) { return vowels.find(c) != string::npos; } );
```

See that version run live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/398a28d26bc45454)</kbd>.

Comment: Is this `auto s = string();` not `auto` gone mad? Why not `string s;`?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: in a program this size, it doesn't really matter. As a matter of habit and consistency in a code base, it does. I am a fan of "[Almost Always Auto](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)" style, and I use it consistently in my code so that the type is on the right. See the other arguments in #4 in the provided link.

Comment: Well, I am not a fan of that style, and I think it makes the code, even for this short example, much less readable. Just look at it! Read down the left-hand side of the code and you cannot tell what the type of anything is.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: That objection is also addressed in the cited article. I admit it's a matter of taste, but the more Python or generic C++ code I write, the more I like it. I have seen multiple co-workers strongly object to that style but become converts once they became accustomed to it. It has all the benefits of dynamic/duck typing like in Python but with actual static checking that we in statically typed languages rely on to aid in correctness of our programs.

Comment: I have read the article, some time ago, and I thought it was bollocks. I don't believe there are significant benefits (as opposed to significant problems) for duck-typing in any language.

Comment: It's a conspiracy to make C++ type agnostic.... Imagine the fun tracking down problems in a 3400 line source filled with nothing but `auto`...

Comment: @NeilButterworth The main benefit of duck typing is that you focus on what the object can do (the content of its interface), not the specific type name. Inside C++ templates, it is a great boon since you have a lot less `typename` litter. Once I was used to it there, it was easy for me to see the same benefits elsewhere. But YMMV.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: C++ is and always will be statically typed. The question is, do **I** need to explicitly commit to types everywhere? The compiler is very good -- generally much better than humans -- at knowing what types should go where. So, I let it figure it out. The types are still checked statically. To me, it feels similar to const-correctness -- letting the compiler keep me honest.

Comment: This is getting out of hand, but knowing what the type of a variable is is key to reading and understanding code. If I see something like `auto a = f();` I have no idea what `a` is unless I track down what `f` is, which is easier said than done. Anyway, this is my last word on the subject.

Comment: I was just picking on you a bit. I understand the usage. But in a long source, the exclusive use of `auto` almost makes you go back picking through the code to find the declaration or instantation to determine the type from a human perspective.

Comment: I don't understand all the fuzz about `auto`. People (including C++ developers) somehow love `python`, but since when do you write in `int a = 0` in `python`? Just use a proper IDE if you always in each line want to know the type of a variable.

Comment: @SerkanT.: No one writes that, and that's the point. In Python or in a C++ function template, you might write code like `auto foundIter = data.find( value )`, and you don't have to care about the types of `foundIter`, `data`, or `value`. The compiler figures it out. If it can't, you get a compile-time error -- static type checking FTW!

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I think the more compelling counter-argument is, not in a debugger, where you have often have IntelliSense-style support (as long as you're not a vimmer), but in code reviews where you don't have that support. Even so, AAA all the way (well, ALMOST all the way).

Comment: @metal Of course no one writes that, it was a joke. I just wanted to make a point that in `python` you don't have explicit types and no one literally cares, in contrary, people love it. But somehow in C++, it is a no-go for some folks.

Comment: @SerkanT.: Sorry, I misunderstood what your first comment was saying. \*high five*